# What is the best way to handle DialogFragment callbacks?

Tags: android, dialog, callback, fragment

I've been using `DialogFragment` to handle Dialogs on an app.

I've read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) which gives some examples about how to use it, but it always uses things like:

```
((FragmentAlertDialog)getActivity()).doPositiveClick();
((FragmentAlertDialog)getActivity()).doNegativeClick();
```

I don't really like this implementation as it **obliges a cast to a pre-known Activity** so it's not very robust.

I also know that **passing and storing a callback inside the `FragmentDialog` isn't a good option** because if it references an Activity, after rotation for example, that activity could have been destroyed... and the callback is not updated.

Also updating the callback when an activity passes `onResume` is also not a very viable option, as it had to know which Dialog is being shown and set a callback related to it making the logic a bit tricky on larger apps.

**So what implementation do you suggest to avoid casts while retaining always the most up-to-date callback?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've enumerated the reasons why callbacks can't be used, very eloquently. Unfortunately, I think the cast (or something similar) is unavoidable. The whole paradigm is rather awkward, frankly.

You could use an interface, if you plan to share a dialog fragment between multiple activities.

```
 ((IXyzDialogHost)GetActivity())->onSomethingHappened()
```

There's something to be said for that approach, I suppose. I can't say I've used that approach myself, personally, but thinking about it, I might be tempted to do so moving forward. At least you can enforce a contract on the calling Activity with an appropriate static DialogFragment.Create method, which deals with the setting of the bundle the fragment manager transaction, and other unpleasantries:

```
 class XyzDialogFragment {
   {
         public static DialogFragment Create(IXyzDialogHost activity, ...)
         {
            ...
         }

   }
```

But there's still a cast.